# Can not run flutter project , file picker error

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I have used file picker in my project , after upgrading my dependencies I can not run my project .

The error is given bellow :

```
/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Warning: The plugin flutter_local_notifications requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin file_picker requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
/home/d0tb0t/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-5.2.5/android/src/main/java/com/mr/flutter/plugin/filepicker/FilePickerDelegate.java:215: error: method getParcelableArrayList in class Bundle cannot be applied to given types;
            return bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedItems", Parcelable.class);
                         ^
  required: String
  found: String,Class<Parcelable>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Parcelable declared in method <T>getParcelableArrayList(String)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':file_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

want to run my app without error

Answer (score 0):

from i read from your error, you need to upgrade your android SDK to 33 from this

> The plugin flutter_local_notifications requires Android SDK version 33.

> The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 33

change your android SDK to a higher version in your `Android -> App -> Build.gradle`

```
  defaultConfig {
        .....
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and it should work properly now :)